# Angular 2 app : How to load the value of a variable type Subject (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I'm working on an Angular2 app , I'm loading a data from a service to my component as a subject

```
public  type1Choisi: any;

constructor(
  public formeService: FormeService, ...) {
    this.formeService._type1.subscribe(type1 => this.type1Choisi = type1);
}
```

and I'm using its value perfectly in my html view :

```
Type 1 selectionnè est :{{type1Choisi}}
```

but I'm not able to use it in my ts file of my component to do same processing :

```
if (this.type1Choisi ===102){  //Here type1Choisi doesn't give the value
  ParamService.dormant.Porte_ON = 1.00;
}
```

am declaring my data in the service as subject

```
public _type1 = new Subject();
```

Anybody may tell me how can i use my sybject not ontly in my view but also in my ts code ????

Comment: Do you have any error in your log? If you print this.type1Choisi in your console what is showing?

Answer (score 0):

To get a value from a subject, you need to subscribe on it:

```
this._type1.subscribe(
  (event) => {
  }
);
```

When an event is received on it, the callback defined when subscribing will be called.

You can send an event this way:

```
this._type1.emit('some string event');
```

Comment: i have already done it , and i wanna load the value of the output variable :   this.formeService._type1.subscribe(type1 => this.type1Choisi = type1);
========> type1CHoisi ????

Comment: Where do you want to use this property? When the callback is triggered?

Comment: i wanna load the value of  " type1Choisi " to use it in a further traitement on another variable , at least how can i display it value :  (console.log(this.type1CHoisi) ) ??,

Comment: Only based on observables / subjects, it's not possible. They doesn't contain a state but "only" allow you to receive events and errors. You can't load something. That said you can cache it into your service (the last value) using the `do` operator. Here is a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992877/angular-2-best-practice-to-load-data-from-a-server-one-time-and-share-results-t/35993192#35993192.